# Dataframe supported method for transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas pandas dataframe like this

```
+-------+-----------+
| Name  | Attribute |
+-------+-----------+
| James | Tall      |
| James | Bald      |
| Lily  | Fat       |
| Lily  | Tall      |
+-------+-----------+
```

and my expect output is

```
+------+------+------+-----+
| Name | Tall | Bald | Fat |
+------+------+------+-----+
| James|    1 |    1 |   0 |
| Lily |    1 |    0 |   1 |
+------+------+------+-----+
```

My data contains several hundred attributes. Does anyone have experience with this kind of transformation?

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['Name', 'Attribute']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)`